# Updating to my database doesnt work in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

**I am trying to update values that i have been able to view. It doesn't seem to error however nothing seems to be updating either. Can anyone help me identify where its not updating? please**

```
<?php

 // check for errors
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 //calls connection
require_once('connection.php');

 //view first table
 $ResultSets = getResults("members");

 echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='6'>";
echo "<tr> <th>member_id</th> <th>first_name</th> <th>second_name</th> <th>Email</th> ";

foreach ($ResultSets as $record) {
echo "<form action=index.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['member_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['first_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['second_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['email'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value =" . $record ['member_id'] . " </td>";
//echo "</tr>";
echo "<input type=submit name=update value=Update>" . " </td>";
 }

echo "<table>";
echo "</form>";

 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

$updateQuery = "UPDATE members SET first_name='$_POST[first_name]', second_name='$_POST[second_name]', email='$_POST[email]' WHERE  member_id='$_POST[hidden]'";

mysql_query($updateQuery);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure when you want to update that `$_POST['update']` is really set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, you are also passing the `member_id` as a string, while I'm sure it is an integer in the database.  Try:

`$updateQuery = "UPDATE members SET first_name='$_POST[first_name]', second_name='$_POST[second_name]', email='$_POST[email]' WHERE  member_id=$_POST[hidden]";`

Answer (score 1):

All of your inputs have the name of topic.

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['member_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['first_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['second_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topic value =" . $record ['email'] . " </td>";
```

needs to be changed to

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=member_id value =" . $record ['member_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=first_name value =" . $record ['first_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=second_name value =" . $record ['second_name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=email value =" . $record ['email'] . " </td>";
```

Comment: Bob, do an echo on your $updateQuery and see how the sql looks.  That will tell you exactly what is not working.  I am guessing you are not getting the member_id back correctly.